# Get LDAP TokenGroups using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols in .NET5

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, .net-5

I'm porting some code from `System.DirectoryServices` to `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` due to the need to run on linux.

The majority of the code is fine but this little piece that retrieves `tokenGroups` isn't coming across.

The original code reads:

```
using (var ldapObject = new DirectoryEntry(objectPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
        {
            ldapObject.Options.Referral = ReferralChasingOption.All;
            ldapObject.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });
            foreach (byte[] sid in ldapObject.Properties["tokenGroups"])
            {
                // Won't run on linux
                var groupSID = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0).ToString();
                try
                {
                    var group = this.GetSecurityGroupBySID(groupSID);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Warn($"Failed to get group with SID {groupSID}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Where `objectPath` is of the form `$"LDAP://{domainName}/{distinguishedName}"`

My attempt looks like this:

```
public void GetExpandedGroups(string objectMail, LdapConnection ldapConnection)
        {
            var usersPath = "OU=active,OU=users,DC=path,DC=etc"; //Not real values
            var filter = $"(&(objectClass = user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:= 2)(mail={objectMail}))";
            var request = new SearchRequest(usersPath, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] { "tokenGroups" });
            request.Controls.Add(new SecurityDescriptorFlagControl(SecurityMasks.Dacl | SecurityMasks.Group | SecurityMasks.Owner));

            var ldapObject = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(request); // Error thrown here

            foreach (byte[] sid in ldapObject.Entries[0].Attributes["tokenGroups"])
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
        }
```

Whenever this runs I get an error, thrown. The stack trace and error response are below:

```
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.<ConstructResponseAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request)
   at LDAPTesting.Connectors.Protocols.GetExpandedGroups(String objectMail, LdapConnection ldapConnection) in C:\code\LDAPTesting\LDAPTesting\Connectors\Protocols.cs:line 62
   at LDAPTesting.Connectors.Protocols.GetGroups() in C:\code\LDAPTesting\LDAPTesting\Connectors\Protocols.cs:line 103
   at LDAPTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\code\LDAPTesting\LDAPTesting\Program.cs:line 17
```

```
00002120: SvcErr: DSID-031404CC, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
```

My thoughts are that I'm querying the wrong path but it looks to match the path that the original code requests on so I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Having tracked down the error here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--8200-8999- I now recognise that it's because these searches can only be performed for a base search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes along this, the solution is incredibly simple.

The `SearchRequest` object needs to be of the scope Base. Really obvious when reading what the error message. So the line:

```
var request = new SearchRequest(usersPath, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] { "tokenGroups" });
```

Should instead read:

```
var request = new SearchRequest(usersPath, filter, SearchScope.Base, new string[] { "tokenGroups" });
```

I had a feeling that there would be an obvious and simple answer due to overlooking something and indeed there was!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution - it's just the first value that is not correct - if that is ignored, everything works fine!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).